# Exercise breakdown in mm:ss and exercise/second

Tags: google-sheets

[image: Current exercise]

It's a workout of 11 minutes with *As Many Reps As Possible*.

I have no coding experience and very primitive google functions knowledge.

Column B is set 'number' of exercise.
Column C is the 'running' time.
Column D is the is how long I actually took time for given exercise.

Both C&D are in hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds format. I would prefer them only in `mm:s`s but for some reason values wouldn't hold to given function when I type in data despite me selecting duration and modifying it to mm:ss (it goes back to hr:mm:ss AM).

Column E is also where I am having trouble in which I would like to know how many individual item/reps (i.e., pushups or burpees) I did per second 
I would also like to compare previous time versus.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between duration formats and time formats is that duration formats begin with one of "elapsed hours", "elapsed minutes", or "elapsed seconds".  (The subsequent fields are simply minutes or seconds). The default duration format is

```
elapsed hours : minutes : seconds
```

If you delete the first field and do nothing else, it's no longer recognized as duration. What you want is to enter

```
elapsed minutes : seconds
```

under "more date and time formats" in the menu. Screenshot:

> [image: pick format]

The drop-down arrow to the left of "Apply" is where you get these options from.

#### Internals

Note that any kind of formatting affects only what you see in the spreadsheet. The representation for the purpose of entering data stays the same: you need to enter 0:3:41 to get 3 minutes 41 seconds. And in the formula bar this will be shown as 00:03:41.000, though in the spreadsheet you'll see 3:41.